# Getting TemporaryFailureException on batch insert

Tags: java, couchbase, batch-insert

I am doing a batch insert of data to CouchBase and getting this exception after few minutes:

> com.couchbase.client.java.error.TemporaryFailureException         at
>   com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncBucket$13.call(CouchbaseAsyncBucket.java:445)
>         at
>   com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncBucket$13.call(CouchbaseAsyncBucket.java:426)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
>         at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onNext(Subscribers.java:234)      at
>   rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.onNext(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:222)
>         at rx.subjects.AsyncSubject.onCompleted(AsyncSubject.java:101)      at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler$1.call(AbstractGenericHandler.java:265)
>         at
>   rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
>         at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Here is the code:

```
    cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create();
    Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket();

    int numBatchs = 10000;
    int numDocsInBatch = 1000;

    for (int j = 0; j < numBatchs; j++) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<JsonDocument> documents = new ArrayList<>(numDocsInBatch);
        for (int i = 0; i < numDocsInBatch; i++) {
            String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis();

            JsonObject user = JsonObject.
                    empty();

            documents.add(JsonDocument.create(uniqueID, user));
        }

        Observable
                .from(documents)
                .flatMap(new Func1<JsonDocument, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<JsonDocument> call(final JsonDocument docToInsert) {
                        return bucket.async().insert(docToInsert);
                    }
                })
                .last()
                .toBlocking()
                .single();
```

Anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TemporaryFailureException` normally caused because server may too busy, Normally the operation can be retried with backoff.

For reference: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/java-2.2/documents-bulk.html

Comment: Naturally batch inserting huge amount of documents causes the server to be busy, but I was not expecting that a server will throw an exception for this reason...

Comment: Couchbase did not met your expectation ;)

Comment: you are storing batches of 1000 documents, 10'000 times, that's 10'000'000 (ten million) insertions... how is your bucket dimensioned in terms of RAM?

Comment: I have 4GB of memory dedicated for CouchBase. At this point I only insert data and I keep getting this exception. I would like to start with about 100M rows test.